# C# Generic Method with a Parameter of that Type has no Properties on the Parameter

Tags: c#, generics, methods

So, that title might be confusing, I'll try to explain. Let's say I have this code here:

```
public void Method<CustomClass>(CustomClass e) {
    e.CustomMethod();
}
```

That line inside of the method, the `e.GetCustomProperty()`, will cause the compile to throw a temper tantrum. It seems that the class is only an object, and nothing more. I am able to do the very basics, such as `e.ToString()`, etc. These properties and methods are, however, present on the object, as I am able to use reflection to gain access to that method, like this:

```
public void Method<CustomClass>(CustomClass e) {
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(CustomClass).GetMethod("CustomMethod");
    method.Invoke(e, new object[] { });
}
```

The above method will compile perfectly with no issues. What exactly is the reason behind this? And is there a way around this, or will I have to use reflection?

Thank you in advance. (I have checked for about half an hour now, using specific and nonspecific search terms on Google and StackOverFlow and have not been able to find another question similar to this, so if it is a duplicate, I'll probably just cry myself to sleep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void Method<T>(T e) where T : CustomClass
{
    e.CustomMethod();
}
```

This tells compiler that generic type T is CustomClass or derived from CustomClass. Therefore you'll be able to call any method without reflection. Also please check that CustomMethod's access modifier allows the call.

Comment: I wish I could mark two solutions as correct D: Your solution provides a simple solution, basically packing what @Rufus L said into a little demo. I think I'll mark his correct though, as it explains exactly what the issue is. Thank you :)

Comment: @CJBurkey - The be frank I think that Rufus's answer overshot the mark a bit. He's perfectly correct, but there is no need to introduce an interface to solve this problem. He's over specified the solution. Casperbear's solution, however, is simple and perfect. IMHO, you should mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity - now that you mention it, I kind of misread this answer. I did actually implement the other solution (I had an interface already that I could use as a dummy, but this is definitely the simpler (and probably preferred) answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to constrain your input type to that of a specific interface which implements a method called `CustomMethod`, then you can add a `where` statement to your method signature that indicates it.

For example, if you have this interface:

```
public interface ICustomInterface
{
    void CustomMethod();
}
```

You can restrict only types that implement that interface (and therefore are guaranteed to have a `CustomMethod` method) by doing this (note also I changed your naming a little to indicate that `CustomType` is actually a generic placeholder by prefixing it with a `T`. Normally people just use `T` by itself in generics):

```
public void Method<TCustomClass>(TCustomClass e) where TCustomClass : ICustomInterface
{
    e.CustomMethod();
}
```

Now if you have a class that implements the interface:

```
public class CustomClass : ICustomInterface
{
    public void CustomMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Custom method called.");
    }
}
```

You can pass it to your generic method:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var customClass = new CustomClass();
    Method(customClass);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]